# No connection using signalR to server

Tags: angular, npm, signalr, ngrx

I try to use npm package ngrx-signalr-core.

I set reducer and effects in app.module.

Now in component I try to establish a connection, but nothing happens. On front I have no info about success or failure. Also on backend I can't see that front is connected.

My component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppState } from 'src/app/app.reducers';
import { Store, Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { createSignalRHub, SignalRHub } from 'ngrx-signalr-core';

@Component({
  selector: 'pdc-package-scenario-matrix-container',
  template: `
    <pdc-header-bar></pdc-header-bar>
    <pdc-matrix-grid></pdc-matrix-grid>
    <div class="flex">
      <pdc-project-details></pdc-project-details>
      <pdc-go-to-banner></pdc-go-to-banner>
    </div>
  `
})

export class PackageScenarioMatrixComponent implements OnInit{

  constructor(private store$: Store<AppState>){
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const hub = {
      hubName: 'cos',
      url: 'https://localhost:50021/packagescenarios'
    };

    this.store$.dispatch(
      createSignalRHub(hub)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I will just assume that you're using .Net Core as the Backend for the SignalR Server. Did you also setup Cors on your Server to [allow incoming connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/security?view=aspnetcore-3.0)? And did you [setup the logging information for SignalR in your Program.cs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-3.0#server-side-logging)?

Comment: Yes, both are added

Comment: My Apologies, but I need to ask: Is it mandatory that you're using the explicit ngrx-signalr-core package? Or is there no way for you to just use the [Official SignalR Packages from Microsoft](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aspnet/signalr)? Afaik using the official packages always takes away the overhead..

Comment: I think yes. Our application is written in redux, so I need to have SignalR in redux. I've made PoC with signalR from MS and it works fine. Unfortunately, when I made it in redux arch, it doesn't work. So I tried this package.

Comment: As taken from the [Official redux.js.org Doc Pages - Where should websockets and other persistent connections live?](https://redux.js.org/faq/code-structure#where-should-websockets-and-other-persistent-connections-live) maybe adding a middleware can help you manage the persistence of connections during an application life time. As far as I understood you can either Implement an existing middleware brought to you by redux.js or implement your own middleware. Quote from the Page : "There's many existing middleware for websockets and other similar connections - see the link below.". All the luck